# Error : SQLite import data from file

Tags: csv, import, sqlite

I am trying to load data from a file which is comma-separated. example:

```
A,positive,9619
A095CDB461A1FEED,positive,1
```

When I am trying to load this file in sqlite3 database I am getting error:

```
sqlite> .mode csv feature_category
sqlite> .import /home/harit/work/python/what-twitter-speaks/classifier/data/snap_data_collection/db-positiveTweets feature_category;
Error: no such table: feature_category;
```

Though the table already exists.

```
sqlite> select * from sqlite_master;
table|feature_category|feature_category|2|CREATE TABLE feature_category(feature, category, count)
table|categorycount|categorycount|3|CREATE TABLE categorycount(category, count)
```

Please help, I am new to sqlite3

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the problem is the semicolon `;` at end of the command.

Try

```
sqlite> .import /home/.../db-positiveTweets feature_category
```