# Error encountered when importing data from csv file into sqlite table

Tags: sqlite, csv

I export the data from Excel 2011. The rows look like:

> 100|Agricultural Production-Crops|Agriculture&Forestry

I create the table in SQLite using:
create table sic (id integer, industry text, category text);
Then I input:

> .mode csv sic

then:

> .separator ","

then:

> .import SIC.csv sic;

And I got the error: "Error: no such table: sic;"
Why? What can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error : SQLite import data from file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290835/error-sqlite-import-data-from-file)

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter is the table name and should be `sic` in your case:

```
.import SIC sic;
```

The first parameter is the filename and should usually end in ".csv" or ".txt" for example (but it doesn't have to). You may want to double check that your filename is correct.

See the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html):

> .import FILE TABLE   -  Import data from FILE into TABLE

Answer (score 0):

I find out from here: http://old.nabble.com/Import-CSV-in-sqlite3--td564241.html.

Exit SQlite 3. And key in:

sqlite3 -separator ',' test.db ".import sic.csv sic"

This solve the problem.