# sqlite3 gives no such table error

Tags: csv, sqlite

I am trying to populate a SQLite database from a csv file on Ubuntu 11.04. I ran the following commands:

```
create table data1 (id integer, city text, bank text, address text);
.separator ","
.import atm_list_india_updated.csv data1
```

Could anyone tell me what is going wrong? Why am I getting this error?

```
sqlite> .tables // shows there is a table called data1
    data1
    sqlite> select * from data1
       ...> ;
    sqlite> .import *******.csv data1;
    Error: no such table: data1; // tells there is no table called data1
    sqlite> .show
         echo: off
      explain: off
      headers: off
         mode: list
    nullvalue: ""
       output: stdout
    separator: ","
        stats: off
        width: 
    sqlite>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error : SQLite import data from file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290835/error-sqlite-import-data-from-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing this helped :

```
create table main(id int(10), bank varchar(255), city varchar(255), address varchar(500))
.separater ","
.import ****.csv data1;
```

Answer (score 22):

As well as other dot-commands that are SQLite shell builtin commands, the `.import` command should not terminate with a semicolon.

Comment: Dude, thank you, I thought I was going crazy. I kept putting the ; at the end!